# Are the Kobold Dragonshields ability scores typos?

Tags: dnd-4e, monsters, kobold

The Kobold Dragonshield from the 4e Monster Manual has a bunch of ability scores that do not match the ability modifiers. For example, their Strength, is 14 (+3). Should it be 16(+3), or 14(+2)? Every single one of their ability scores are wrong like this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Those modifiers include half the creature's level.

From the Monster Manual, p7 (*emphasis mine*):

> **Ability Scores**
> This section shows the monster’s six ability scores, presented
> so that each vertical pair contributes to one of the three
> defenses (Fortitude, Reflex, and Will). Following each score
> in parentheses is the adjusted ability score modifier *including
> one-half the monster’s level*, which is useful whenever the
> monster needs to make an untrained skill check or an ability
> check.

As the Dragonshield is a level 2 creature, half its level rounded down is 1, so its modifiers for ability checks and untrained skill checks are increased by 1 over the base ability modifier (which is not used directly for any purpose, only included in calculating other bonuses).

Note further that the Kobold Slyblade, on the following page, is a level 4 creature and so all of its modifiers in the ability section are *two* higher than would be expected based on its ability scores.

Comment: Thank you. I didn’t notice this on other monsters because the only other ones I looked at where level 1

Comment: @TheDragonOfFlame Yep, the first couple kobolds in that section are level 1 and thus don't receive a half-level bonus.